# Representing 3 Integers Using One Byte?

Tags: character-encoding, binary-data, primitive-types

I have three integers {`a`, `b`, `c`} that range (say) between the following values:

`a` - {1 to 120, in jumps of 1}

`b` - {-100 to 100, in jumps of 5}

`c` - {1 to 10, in jumps of 1}

Due to space considerations, I would like to represent these three values using 1-byte ONLY, meaning, a single integer (in the range of -127..128) will represent the results of {`a`, `b`, `c`} and be stored in a binary format to disk.

Later, when I read the binary data, I will know how to 'parse' this 1-byte to get the values of {`a`, `b`, `c`}.

Any idea how to achieve that?   (note: if need be, in order to support this design, I can 'compromise' on the ranges; for example, say, `a` can be in jumps of 5. `b` can also be in jumps of 10 etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just from a numbers point of view we have:

a = 120 values, b = 41 values, c = 10 values

That makes for a total of 49,200 unique values. A byte can only represent 256 values, so you'd need to use at least 16-bits (two bytes) to represent your range.

One way to do so would be through bit shifting.

As an example, you can store four 8-bit values in a 32-bit value, and extract them like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int pack32(char *v)
{
    return (v[0] << 24) + (v[1] << 16) + (v[2] << 8) + v[3];
}

void unpack32(int a, char *v)
{
    v[0] = a >> 24;
    v[1] = a >> 16;
    v[2] = a >> 8;
    v[3] = a;
}

int main()
{
    char v[4] = {32, 64, 16, 8};

    cout << "Original values: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
        cout << (int)v[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    int q = pack32(v);
    cout << "Packed: " << q << endl;

    unpack32(q, v);
    cout << "Unpacked: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cout << (int)v[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Code relevant to your needs:

```
unsigned short pack32(unsigned a, char b, unsigned c)
{
    // Layout:
    // Bits 0 - 5 are reserved for a
    // Bits 6 - 12 are reserved for b
    // Bits 13 - 15 are reserved for c

    // Assumptions:
    // a is [2, 120] in steps of 2
    // b is [-100, 100] in steps of 5
    // c is [1, 10] in steps of 1

    // Shift a from [2, 120] to [0, 59]
    unsigned a2 = (a - 2) >> 1;
    // Shift b from [-100, 100] to [0, 40]
    unsigned b2 = b / 5 + 20;
    // Shift c from [1, 10] to [0, 9]
    unsigned c2 = c - 1;

    return a2 + (b2 << 5) + (c2 << 12);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I compromise on the ranges?

Comment: @Mike: your code shows him how to pack the information into a 32-bit integer. You could just create `struct x{unsigned char a; signed char b; unsigned char c;};` if that's what you're going to do with bit shifts. Show him how to pack it into 16 bits, where the bit shifts aren't multiples of 8.

Comment: I'm having a total brain fart right now. I posted the code for packing the bits, I'm not sure if I did that right though. I'll have to come back at this later.

Answer (score 2):

a - {1 to 120, in jumps of 1} = 120 values = log2(120) = 6.9 bits

b - {-100 to 100, in jumps of 5} = 41 values = log2(41) = 5.4 bits

c - {1 to 10, in jumps of 1} = 10 values = log2(10) = 3.3 bits

Total = 15.6 bits, so you could pack all these into one 16 bit value, but not into an 8 bit byte.

Comment: What if I compromise on the ranges?

Comment: Use the same approach as above and calculate the number of bits again using the new ranges.

Comment: Thank you. I needed the `log2(X)` explanation to calculate the number of bits.

Comment: This post discusses the **information-theoretical minimums**, given the ranges you requested. To actually implement this would require you to use some kind of compression algorithm or mapping table that can mingle the bits of the different numbers appropriately. If you want simple code to read and write these values (i.e. the bits of each variable are separate), you need to round the numbers of bits up to the nearest integer, in which case the result shown here would be 18 bits.

Comment: @Ken: you don't really need to round the number of bits up for each component, unless perhaps efficiency of packing/unpacking is a concern. And you don't need a very complex encoding scheme. E.g. if x, y and z all have range 0..9 then you can encode this as 100*x + 10*y + z, i.e. you don't need to use 4 bits for each - you can do the whole thing with 10 bits.

Comment: @Paul: you're right about the encoding scheme. I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to compromise quite a lot on your ranges to get everything into a single byte.

For simplicity, you probably want to store each value in a whole number of bits - so work out how many bits you want for each value. For example, you could use:

- a (3 bits)
- b (3 bits)
- c (2 bits)

That will give you 8 different values for `a`, 8 different values for `b`, and 4 different values for `c`. That's much *much* less information than you originally had, of course. Once you've chosen a scheme like that, the rest is just a matter of:

- Converting each original value into its "compressed" pattern (e.g. for `a` you may represent 1 as 0, and 120 as 7)
- Combining the three compressed values into a single byte (using bit-shifting and bitwise OR)
- Later splitting the single byte into the three compressed values (using bit-shifting and masking)
- Converting each compressed value into an "uncompressed" value which is reasonably close to the original value

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mike's answer, but with the numbers correct:

a = 120 values, b = 41 values, c = 10 values

That makes for a total of 49,200 unique values. A byte can only represent 256 values, so you'd need to use at least 16-bits (two bytes) to represent your range.

Now let's suppose we want to use different bits to represent each of these numbers (i.e. no compression that mingles these somehow):

`a` fits comfortably in 7 bits, `b` fits comfortably in 6 bits, and `c` fits comfortably in 4 bits. (By "fits comfortably", I mean that's the smallest integer number of bits this data can fit in.) That's 17 bits, so without applying some kind of compression you might as well use a separate byte for each value.

Now, let's discuss a way to fit this into one character by changing step sizes in these values.

You can divide these up into two 2-bit values (allowing 4 values each) and one 4-bit value. Or you can divide these up into two 3-bit values (allowing 8 values each) and one 2-bit value. You can decide how to assign these to your variables `a`, `b`, and `c`.

The best way to store these in C is with a struct containing bit fields:

```
struct myvalues{
  unsigned a:3;
  signed b:3;
  unsigned c:2;
};
//look at your compiler and platform documentation 
//to make sure you can pack this properly
```

Then you can access the fields `a`, `b`, and `c`, by name directly (though you'll have to do some math to convert the values.)

Other languages (Java, C#, etc.) aren't so flexible about how you define types, so you'll need to resort to bit shifts in those languages.